# Am i doing correct the Directional derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

im trying to find Directional derivative,I done few examples and im not sure if im doing it correct, so please tell me if im right...
A. I need to find the Directional derivative of $$ u=arcsin(\frac{z} {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$$ at the point $A=(1,1,1)$  in the direction of vector $AN$ while $$N=(3,2,3)$$
I calculated $AN=(2,1,2)$ I calculated the vector normal to be $(\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$ then found the partial derivative of $u$ at $A=(1,1,1)$ to be $(1,1,\frac{1}{\sqrt2})$ and found out that the Directional derivative is : $\frac{2}{3} *1+\frac{1}{3} *1 + \frac{2}{3} * \frac{1}{\sqrt2} =1+ \frac{\sqrt2}{3}$
am i  correct?
thanks!

Comment: Partial derivative? Do you mean the function's gradient?

Comment: @Joanpemo I mean Directional derivative...

Comment: You wrote "...then found the partial derivate at $\;A\;$ ..." ...did you mean the gradient, here?

Comment: @Joanpemo no... I mean that i found the partial derivative $U_x$ ,$U_y$,$U_z$ at the point $A$

Comment: *That* is the gradient of $\;u\;$ , a vector: $\;\nabla u=(u_x,u_y,u_z)\;$

Comment: @Joanpemo so my way is wrong?....

Comment: I think so, but take a peek at my answer: I got a different value for the gradient at $\;(1,1,1)\;$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function is differentiable at $\;(1,1,1)\;$ it is way easier:

$$D_{AN}(u)=\nabla u(1,1,1)\cdot\frac{AN}{||AN||}$$

Now:

$$\nabla u(x,y,z)=$$

$$\left(\frac{-xz}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac{z^2}{x^2+y^2}}}\,,\frac{-yz}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac{z^2}{x^2+y^2}}}\,,\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac{z^2}{x^2+y^2}}}\right)=$$

$$\left(\,-\frac{xz}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2-z^2}}\,,\,\,-\frac{yz}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2-z^2}}\,,\,\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-z^2}}\,\right)\implies$$

$$\nabla u(1,1,1)=\left(\,-\frac12\,,\,\,-\frac12\,,\,\,1\,\right)$$

so I get

$$D_{AN}(u)|_{(1,1,1)}=\left(-\frac12,-\frac12,1\right)\cdot(2,1,2)\cdot\frac13=-\frac16$$

Check the above, lest I made some mistake.

Comment: @user152711 Observe that $$\,\left((x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}\right)'_x=-\frac122x(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}=-\frac x{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$ I'm pretty certain you're omitting the minus signs in thefirst two coordinates

Comment: Correct its my mistake... Thanks!